# Access 2010 VBA Error 2425 "The expression you entered has a function name that database can't find"

Tags: vba, ms-access, autoexec

In Access 2010, I have an Autoexec macro that calls a function (not a sub, a function) called CloseAllToolbars().

In the .MDB file, when I open it, it runs the function just fine.
I Save & Publish it to an .MDE, the .MDE runs the function just fine.
I copy the .MDE across to a brand new laptop running Windows 10 without Office or Access installed. I have installed the Access Runtime 2010. My development PC is also Windows 10.

When I run this MDE on the new laptop, it gives me the error message 2425 "The expression you entered has a function name that database can't find".

Comment: Looks like new laptop doesn't have library(s) you referenced in the application.

Answer (score 6):

I discovered through another post on another site that the Access Runtime has a problem with functions being called from the AutoExec. The solution was to run the SP1 for the Access Runtime, which should fix it.

I discovered that there is now a SP2 out for Access 2010 Runtime (available here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=39643). It solved my problem.